# presentViewController hides presentingViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

Is there a way to present a ViewController in iOS while keeping the presenting ViewController visible? Right now the PresentingViewController seems to be hidden as soon as the animation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the values from `UIModalPresentationStyle` to control this.

`UIModalPresentationPageSheet` or `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` will result in presentations which leave an amount of the *presenting* view controller below.

Set `modalPresentationStyle` on the view controller which is being *presented*

e.g

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[presentingViewController presentViewController:presentedViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: How and where should I set the presentedViewControllers view size to fit the screen again?

Comment: Use UIModalPresentationFullScreen to get full screen back again

Comment: So first I set the VC's modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationPageSheet and then... When do I set the modalPresentationStyle to UIModalPresentationFullscreen? Could you provide some example code?

Comment: or you could try it out for yourself? part of writing code involves experimenting. see edit…

Comment: Ok I'll ask differently. How can I set the size of the VC presented as a ModalFormSheet? This seems to be pretty fixed.

Comment: ModalFormSheet is fixed in size . Seek tutorials on custom uiviewcontroller transition for more control e.g http://maniacdev.com/2013/08/tutorial-how-to-create-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Answer (score 0):

Show:

```
if let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopupVC") as? PopupVC
    {
        var frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height
        overlayWindow = UIWindow(frame: frame)

        popupVC.overlayWindow = overlayWindow
        overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
        overlayWindow.rootViewController = popupVC

        overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations:
        {
            self.overlayWindow.frame.origin.y = 0
        })
    }
```

Hide in PopupVC

```
 if let window = overlayWindow
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            window.frame.origin.y = window.frame.height
        }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
            self.overlayWindow = nil
        })
    }
```